# Rails .all returns a Relation with objects, but .count and .all.to_a doesn't return anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot, byebug

I'm currently having a very weird issue at the moment. I have an `ExportFile` model. Within a `byebug` console inside the tests, if I call `.all`, I see:

```
>>> ExportFile.all
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<ExportFile id: 189, sequence_number: 1, filename: "DB_EXPORT_20151106173840.zip", status: 3, content: 2, created_at: "2015-12-09 12:54:56", updated_at: "2015-12-09 12:54:56", first_transfer_date: nil, failed_transfer_count: 0, successful_transfer_date: "2015-12-01 12:54:56">, #<ExportFile id: 190, sequence_number: 2, filename: "DB_EXPORT_20151106173840.zip", status: 3, content: 2, created_at: "2015-12-09 12:54:56", updated_at: "2015-12-09 12:54:56", first_transfer_date: nil, failed_transfer_count: 0, successful_transfer_date: "2015-12-01 12:54:56">, #<ExportFile id: 191, sequence_number: 3, filename: "DB_EXPORT_20151106173840.zip", status: 3, content: 2, created_at: "2015-12-09 12:54:56", updated_at: "2015-12-09 12:54:56", first_transfer_date: nil, failed_transfer_count: 0, successful_transfer_date: "2015-12-01 12:54:56">, #<ExportFile id: 192, sequence_number: 4, filename: "DB_EXPORT_20151106173840.zip", status: 3, content: 2, created_at: "2015-12-09 12:54:56", updated_at: "2015-12-09 12:54:56", first_transfer_date: nil, failed_transfer_count: 0, successful_transfer_date: "2015-12-01 12:54:56">, #<ExportFile id: 193, sequence_number: 5, filename: "DB_EXPORT_20151106173840.zip", status: 3, content: 2, created_at: "2015-12-09 12:54:56", updated_at: "2015-12-09 12:54:56", first_transfer_date: nil, failed_transfer_count: 0, successful_transfer_date: "2015-12-01 12:54:56">]>
```

But if I try `.count`, or `.all.to_a`, I get nothing:

```
>>> ExportFile.count
0
>>> ExportFile.all.to_a
[]
```

Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong? Before running the above snippets I use `FactoryGirl.create_list(:export_file, 5)`, if it does make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the thing is that you are in console in development mode, but FactoryGirl creates records in test database, thus you do not have access to them.

I think, that if you seed the development database with `ExportData` records, they'd be there for you.

Comment: No, the console was actually a `byebug` console in one of the tests.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that upgrading `byebug` solved this issue. I've upgraded from 8.1.0 to 8.2.1. Very strange...

Comment: hm. This is indeed strange, but happens to very rarely, that updating the gem solves the issue

Comment: The problem was that if I dropped `byebug` inside an example, it caused the above behaviour. If i removed it and used `puts` to output `.count`, it worked as expected. Therefore, it must've been something with `byebug`, although these kind of bugs are **very** hard to spot.